# Fast forward and rewind is not working in nodejs server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am running nodejs server to establish a video annotation tool. But problem is i am not able to run fast forward and rewind functionality. This is my node-js server.js file:

Video file is in html not in server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    console.log('request starting...');

    var filePath = '.' + request.url;
    if (filePath == './')
        filePath = './dragnew_popup.html';

    var extname = path.extname(filePath);
    var contentType = 'text/html';
    switch (extname) {
        case '.js':
            contentType = 'text/javascript';
            break;
        case '.css':
            contentType = 'text/css';
            break;
        case '.json':
            contentType = 'application/json';
            break;
        case '.png':
            contentType = 'image/png';
            break;      
        case '.mp4':
            contentType = 'video/mp4';
            break;
    }

    fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
        if (error) {
            if(error.code == 'ENOENT'){
                fs.readFile('./404.html', function(error, content) {
                    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
                    response.end(content, 'utf-8');
                });
            }
            else {
                response.writeHead(500);
                response.end('Sorry, check with the site admin for error: '+error.code+' ..\n');
                response.end(); 
            }
        }
        else {
            response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
            response.end(content, 'utf-8');
        }
     });

 }).listen(8080);
 console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
```

when i run this server.js I am not able to use fast forward and rewind but i can play and pause only.

so Where I've to make the changes so that I can use fast forward and rewind?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the server need to support range requests, so that the browser can get the content starting from your desired position.

You could start with this mdn document [Range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) to handle range header correctly and respond the request with correct headers and status code.

I found a page [video streaming with nodejs](https://websnippet.io/post/video-streaming-with-nodejs/) to help you build the simple server from scratch.

However, if you dont need too much costumization, a well-tested npm module  about static file server may be more robust.

Comment: but this will work when you have mentioned video file name in server.js but in my case video implementation is done in html file so this same range request will work?

Comment: I did same thing with http-server but I wanted to edit local JSON file. SO Is it possible with http-server? and How?

Comment: About your first question, if you store your video as buffer in memory, you could use Buffer#slice to respond with partial buffer.

Comment: Can you explain me clearly because I didn't get what you are telling. Is there any example for the same, please send.

Comment: About your second question, as the author stated, it's a readonly server. If you need a server with more freedom, either you could try to implement it manually, or you could use some more generic server modules such as `koa`, and use `koa-router` middleware to route different kinds of requests, routing different requests to different handlers. Note that the second approach is more complicated to learn and write at first, yet it is more scalable and product-ready. It all depends on your decision.

Comment: To explain it clearly, first how is your video stored in memory?

Comment: Currently video is in local storage only

Comment: Er, maybe I misunderstand your need. Your video content is stored in the browser, so it should be able to manipulate(rewind, fast forward) with pure client script. I will look into it later. But when you mentioned localstorage, I remember that the max size is 5MB, won't your video exceed that limit?

Comment: And could you post some relevant client-side code, I am interested in how you store your video in localstorage

Comment: I am fetching video from local storage via HTML tag:  '<video id="video"  controls="true" width="1280" height="720">
            <source src="out1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>'

Comment: I will tell you what I need exactly....So there is a annotation I am working on and in that i am getting video and JSON (it contains boundingbox data of object in video) and this both I will merge it and Review it. Now assume that I wanted to edit some rectangle bounding box in that So using fabricjs I will edit and once I press save button, the updated data has to save it into same JSON file. But How to save new data into same JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

I created one more node.js server for video and kept it into 3000 port. And one more server to run my .html file. in this html file I kept http://ip-address:8080/video>.

SO whenever I ask my html to run video it will send request to video server to play and whenever I ask for fast forward and rewind it will send request to video server and html server will get reply for the same.

This is what I wanted.

Thank you everyone for giving me your precious time.